# Show that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is an even number, for positive integers $n$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

> Show by a combinatorial proof that
>
> $$\dbinom{2n}{n}$$
>
> is an even number, where $n$ is a positive integer.

I tried to solve this problem but I can't.

Comment: Are you asking whether $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ is an even number or are you asking for combinatorial proof of $\dbinom{2n}{n} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

Comment: sorry! $\dbinom{2n}{n} \text{is even number}$

Comment: @Math1000 I think $\mathbb N$ was supposed to be the set of **positive** integers, seeing as the assertion "$\binom{2n}n$ is an even number" is false for $n=0$.

Comment: Oh, fair enough, $\binom 00=1$. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be familiar with the recursive definition of the binomial coefficients, that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$

\begin{matrix}1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1\\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots&\ddots\\
 & \cdots& \binom{n-1}{r-1} & \binom{n-1}{r} & \cdots\\
 & \cdots& & \binom{n}{r} & \cdots\end{matrix}

Now, notice that $\binom{2n}{n} = \binom{2n-1}{n-1} + \binom{2n-1}{n}$

Notice further that $\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \binom{2n-1}{(2n-1)-(n-1)} = \binom{2n-1}{n}$

So, $\binom{2n}{n} = 2\cdot \binom{2n-1}{n}$ and is therefore even.

---

The combinatorial proof of the recursive definition is that to choose $r$ objects out of $n$ with one *special* object, either the special object *is* in the choosing or it is not.  Breaking it into cases, if it is, you still need to choose $r-1$ objects out of the $n-1$ remaining.  If it is not, then you still need to choose $r$ objects out of the $n-1$ remaining.

Hence $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$

Comment: I should think also that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$ should be clear as well and assumed knowledge, but if it requires proof, note that to choose $r$ good objects out of $n$ with the rest bad, it is equivalent to choosing $n-r$ *bad* objects out of $n$ with the rest good.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be all subsets of $T=\{1,2,3,\dots,2n\}$ of size $n$. There is an equivalence relation on $S$ where every equivalence class has two elements, $\{A,T\setminus A\}$.

Comment: what do you mean there is an equivalent relation or $S$?

Comment: Do you know what an equivalence relation is, @TheEmperorofIceCream

Comment: I don't know why either there is $S$ or there is an equivalence relation.

Comment: That sentence is unclear, @TheEmperorofIceCream

Comment: There is an equivalence relation or S where every equivalence class has two elements, {A,T∖A}.

Comment: There is an equivalence relation or S?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Ah, you were just objecting to the typo "or." That would have been much clearer if you had quoted that. I meant "on."

Comment: Now it makes sense.

Comment: Another way to phrase this: Every selection of $n$ winners from a group of $2n$ is paired with a corresponding selection of $n$ losers.

Answer (score 1):

Does this count?  Count the number of ways to create a subset from a set of $2n$ elements.  For each element, it's either in the set or out of the set for a total of $2^{2n}$ subsets.  Now, these subsets can have any size from $0$ to $2n$, so we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k=2^{2n}$$

Now, choosing $k$ elements to include in the subset is the same as selecting $2n-k$ elements to exclude, or

$$\binom{2n}k=\binom{2n}{2n-k}$$

Now we can simply reorder the sum and the rest is algebra

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k=\binom{2n}n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\binom{2n}k+\binom{2n}{2n-k}\right]=\binom{2n}n+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}k=2^{2n}$$

$$\binom{2n}n=2\left[2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}k\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{n}{0}^2+\binom{n}{1}^2+\dots \binom{n}{n}^2\equiv \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\dots \binom{n}{n}=2^n$

---

$2^n\binom{2n}{n}=\color{red}{\binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{2}+\dots \binom{2n}{n-1}}+\color{blue}{\binom{2n}{n+1}+\binom{2n}{n+2}+\dots\binom{2n}{2n}}=2\binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{2}+\dots \binom{2n}{n-1}$ and hence odd.

---

The [Kneser graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph) $K(2n,n)$ has $\binom{2n}{n}$ vertices and is $1$-regular. Since the number of odd vertices in any graph is even, $\binom{2n}{n}$ is even.

Comment: That's not a combinatorial proof.

Comment: It has a combinatorial aspect to it.

Comment: Not really, no. It uses a result that has a combinatorial proof, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: I added some other proofs.